# XCode 4.3.3 sqlite3 error even after importing and including frameworks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

When I run my XCode project using sqlite3, I keep getting the same two errors (appearing between **):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CalendarDatabase", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o**
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

I looked everywhere for an answer but all I find is problems with importing sqlite3 and including frameworks. But I've included `libsqlite3.0.dylib` and `libsqlite3.dylib` and I've imported sqlite3 using `#import "sqlite3.h"`. I'm still getting these errors. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the error message, the words `for architecture i386` tells me that your dylibs do **not** have i386 code (only x86_64). If you're compiling for i386 (32 bits), you'll need either fat dylibs (x86_64 + i386), or 32-bit dylibs.

Comment: how do i get fat dylibs or 32-bit dylibs?

Comment: You'll probably have to compile them yourself.

Comment: how would i begin to do that? i'm sorry but i'm kinda new to this stuff.

Comment: Do you have any experience with gcc? If not, this is going to be a painful experience. Also, why are you compiling for 32-bit?

Comment: i dont have any experience with gcc. is there anyway i can change from compiling for 32-bit, im not sure what i did to make it compile for 32-bit.

Comment: In the Build Settings. Section: Architectures.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Build Settings.